# socket.emit issue into post method

Tags: node.js, sockets

i want to send datas in same client (not all clients) with this code;

```
    app.post("/search", function(req, res) {
    //some other codes
    //if database saved {
    io.sockets.emit('preview-post', {title: "blabla" });// io variable was declared as GLOBAL
    // } database saved end.
res.send({bla:bla});// response end before database saving process
    });
```

this sample is working ! but it  sends to all clients , How can i emit data to same opened browser(same client) ?

Second Question is: Are there any alternative ways to do this scenario?
My algorithm is  post method fired > async call to an api > response end and page loaded on client > async call to an api is still continue > if async call is finished > send alert to client . But How? i wanted to do it wiht socket .io , if i use your 3.part , it'll work , can i do this scenario any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed sends to all sockets.

There are a couple ways to achieve what you are looking to do. The first way is to do something like this on the server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('search', function(*/ client supplied arguments /*){
    socket.emit('preview-post', {title: "blabla" });
  });
});
```

If you are insistent on using a post request, and then sending it back to the client, there are two ways to achieve this.

The easiest way, if you only need to respond to this response, is just send a standard response from node, and let the client handle it:

```
res.send({
  event: 'preview-post',
  payload: {title: "blabla" }
});
```

This removes socket.io's event system, so if you are insistent on using socket.io to send this event back to the same client, you are going to need to use cookies. Express and the module [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) make this easy for you.

Once you have this setup, inside your request you could do something like this:

```
app.post("/search", function(req, res) {
  var socket = findSocketByCookie(req.cookies.myUniqueCookie);
  socket.emit('preview-post', {title: "blabla" });
});

function findSocketByCookie(cookie) {
  for(var i in io.sockets.connected) {
    var socket = io.sockets.connected[i];
    if(socket.handshake.headers.cookie.indexOf(cookie) !== -1){
      return socket;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this works, or if I can help out at all any more.

Comment: Are the cookies from the `socket.handshake` always automatically stored for use like this?

Comment: What I have seen, so far, yes. At least on socket.io v1.3

Comment: There is another method you could use with using socket.io's rooms, and a unique identifier, if you would like me to explain this more, I can.

Comment: Firstly , thank you for great answer , actually my algorithm is  post method fired > async call to an api > response end and page loaded on client > async call to an api is still continue > if async call is finished > send alert to client . But How? i wanted to do it wiht socket .io , if i use your 3.part , it'll work , can i do this scenario any other way?

Comment: Do you have any example code? I might be able to help with that

Comment: İ will add an example today

Comment: Before add an example , findSocketByCookie function returns "socket" value undefined , cookie works properly but indexOf(cookie) value is "-1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72374/discussion-between-osman-erdi-and-chapinkapa).